# C occasional error when using malloc with struct

Tags: arrays, c, string, memory, allocation

Why I'm getting occasional "core dump " or segfaults when running this code below. It's supposed to load a text file in memory, ignores the first line, then use function process to remove white space (except between parens). If left paren not matched with right one on the same line it's all ignored. It also replaces CR with LF and LF is replaced with asci 1. in the pointer assignment loop LF is temporarily replaced by '\0' to  ease debugging. Processing terminates if '%' or '\0' is encountered.

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef struct {
    uint fSize;    // Number of loaded bytes (file size)
    uint progNum;  // Program number
    uint blockcnt; // Number of blocks in the rogram
    char **block;  // pointer to the block array
    char *data;    // pointer to the actual raw data in file
} PROG;

static PROG *p;

int main() {
    p = NULL;
    int err;

    if (err = loadProg("file.txt", &p))
        printf("Error %d", err);

    // Another call
    freeProg(p);
    if (err = loadProg("file.txt", &p))
        printf("Error %d", err);
}

char *process(char *src, char *dest, int *cnt) {
    char *c, *o, *com;
    int n = 0;
    for (c = src, o = dest;; c++) {
        switch (*c) {
        case ' ':
        case '\r':
        case ')':
            break;

        case '%':
        case '\0':
            *cnt = n;
            *o = '\0';
            return o;

        case '(':
            for (com = o; *c != '\n' &&
                          *c != ')';) // Control in (\n, \0 '(') not allowed %??
                *o++ = *c++;
            if (*c != '\n') {
                *o++ = *c;
                break;
            }
            o = com;
        case '\n':
            n++;
            *o++ = *c;
            *o++ = 1;
            break;

        default:
            *o++ = *c;
        }
    }
}

int loadProg(char *file, PROG **p) {
    FILE *fp;
    PROG *pr;
    char *data, *c;
    long fsize;
    if ((fp = fopen(file, "rb")) == NULL)
        return 1;

    if ((pr = malloc(sizeof(*pr))) == NULL)
        return 2;

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    if ((pr->data = malloc(fsize + 1)) == NULL) {
        freeProg(pr);
        return 2;
    }

    fread(pr->data, fsize, 1, fp); // Read file into mem buffer
    pr->data[fsize] = '\0';
    fclose(fp);

    c = process(strchr(pr->data, '\n') + 1, pr->data, &(pr->blockcnt));
    pr->fSize = c - pr->data + 1;
    pr->data = realloc(pr->data, pr->fSize);
    pr->block = malloc(sizeof(*pr->block) * pr->blockcnt);
    if (pr->data == NULL || pr->block == NULL) {
        freeProg(pr);
        return 2;
    }

    c = pr->data;
    for (int k = 0; k < pr->blockcnt; c++) {
        pr->block[k++] = c;
        for (; *c != '\n'; c++)
            ;
        *c = 0; // terminate with \0 (for debugging only)
    }

    uint usedBytes = pr->fSize + sizeof(pr) + sizeof(pr->block) * pr->blockcnt;
    printf("\nAllocated %d Bytes", usedBytes);

    *p = pr;
    return 0;
}

void freeProg(PROG *prog) {
    if (prog == NULL)
        return;
    free(prog->block);
    free(prog->data);
    free(prog);
    prog = NULL; //
}
```

Comment: When you run it in the debugger where does the crash happen? You may need to use the call stack to find where in your code the problem starts. Is it repeatable with a particular set of input?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't need a `break;` at `case '(':`? what happens if `*c == ')'` after the loop?

Comment: What is `*o++ = 1;` used for?

Comment: @Retired Ninja
It happenes only if I tried to open non exist file and then called loadProg again. Otherwise, it seems like there is no problem.

Comment: @Craig Estey
 It breaks on LF but. Stray ')' will be ignored.

Comment: @Craig , David Ranieri
 *o++ = 1, to replace '\n' . Later on the processed data will be the input of interpreter so I plan to use that byte to hold block flags after pre parsing step in hope to improve execution speed.

Comment: @Avi Berger
This is just a debug phase. later p wont be needed. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @user3479526 ok, then I suggest to add a comment: `/* fallthrough */` at the end of the `case`

Comment: David Ranieri
Good remark

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Actually I did not post all the code. Turns out I have to make `p` `NULL` if `loadProg` returned error if opening a file failed. Thanks all.

Comment: However, is it necessary to malloc to pr? Isn't it already allocated with its declaration PROG *pr ; ?

Comment: anyway you could post a short input text file and the expected output

Comment: PROG * pr; allocates space for the pointer pr. With malloc you allocate space and store a pointer to this space inside of your pr.